# Can't copy a file to an external drive with filemaneger.default.copyItem in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a function that takes a source and a destination URL to copy files with swiftUI.

Here is my function so far:

```
func copyFile(_ fileURL : URL, _ folder : URL) -> Bool {
    let filename = fileURL.lastPathComponent
    let finalDestination = folder.appendingPathComponent(filename)
    
    do {
        print("Trying to create " + finalDestination.deletingLastPathComponent().path)
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: finalDestination.deletingLastPathComponent().path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        print("Creating folder ok !")
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print("Couldn't create directory")
    }
    
    let original_hash = hashFile(fileURL)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: fileURL, to: finalDestination)
    } catch {
        return false
    }
 
    let destination_hash = hashFile(finalDestination)
    
    if original_hash == destination_hash
    { return true }
    
    else { return false }
}
```

It works when I try to copy files to the folders inside my app, however I cannot manage to copy the files anywhere else. Is there a special permission that I need to ask? I'm not sure how.

Thank you,

Comment: What specifically fails ? At what line ? Do you get any output from `print(error)`. Also print and show any error from the `FileManager.copyItem` block

Comment: @WarrenBurton I get this error when I try to create the directory :

`"You don’t have permission to save the file “2020-10-14” in the folder “TestMoveFolder”."`

And this when I try to copyItem: 

`2020-11-08 17:11:20.943609+0100 FileExporter[9118:677053] open on /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4BD0D227-9897-43CD-99B3-75A75CFF7CF0/File%20Provider%20Storage/TestFolder/TestMoveFolder/2020-10-14/DSC06789.ARW: No such file or directory`

Comment: Is this Mac or iOS? If Mac, is your app sandboxed?